# postgresql + nginx runtime error on Windows

Tags: php, windows, postgresql, nginx

I have been trying PHP + nginx on windows, well everythng worked fine until I had to use postgres.

Error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect() in C:\nginx\html\main.php on line 15
```

Whenevr I try initiating a postgres connection this happens.

I checked and there is nothing wrong on line 15(or before or after). I know this as I have specially downloaded and installed WAMP with postgres as database everything works fine.

Comment: you haven't enabled pg in php, so the pg functions aren't loaded.

Comment: what do you get back if run phpinfo() from an HTML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Take a look at the output of phpinfo(). It tells you which php.ini file has been used.
- Open that file in an editor.
- Search for the `extension_dir=...` parameter; it should point to a directory on your machine.
- Take a look in that directory and check whether there is a php_pgsql.dll.
- Back in the php.ini check whether there is a `extension=php_pgsql.dll` parameter.
- If there is a leading semi-colon before that line, remove it (; marks a comment).
- If the line is missing, add it.
- Restart the webserver/apache.
- Check whether phpinfo() prints the postgres section.

Comment: Had to set extension_dir = "C:\nginx\php\ext" as I had moved php inside nginx folder. Also had to start php using "start /b c:\nginx\php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c c:\nginx\php\php.ini" as the "Loaded Configuration File" option was showing "none"

Comment: Works with nginx indeed even if php has not been compiled with pgsql.